# Dynamic pivot query using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following table with the details:

**Example**:

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1
(`PK` int, `Name` varchar(3), `Subject` varchar(9), `Grade` varchar(1));

INSERT INTO Table1
(`PK`, `Name`, `Subject`, `Grade`)
VALUES
(1, 'Bob', 'Math', 'A'),
(2, 'Bob', 'History', 'B'),
(3, 'Bob', 'Language', 'C'),
(4, 'Bob', 'Biology', 'D'),
(5, 'Sue', 'History', 'C'),
(6, 'Sue', 'Math', 'A'),
(7, 'Sue', 'Music', 'A'),
(8, 'Sue', 'Geography', 'C');
```

Now I want to write a store procedure through which I want to pivot the table.

## Attempt

```
 DELIMITER $$
 create PROCEDURE sptest1(IN nm varchar(50),IN sub varchar(50))
 begin
 SET @sql = NULL;

 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN ', nm ,' = ''', nm,
     ''' THEN grade END) `', nm, '`'))
 INTO @sql
 FROM table1;

 SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', sub ,',', @sql, ' 
                 FROM table1 
                GROUP BY ', sub ,'');
select @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling Function:

```
call sptest1('name','subject')
```

But getting wrong result:

```
 subject    name
 ----------------
 Biology    null
 Geography  null
 History    null
 Language   null
 Math       null
 Music      null
```

Expected Result:

```
 subject    Bob     Sue
 -------------------------
 Biology    D       null    
 Geography  null    C
 History    B       C
 Language   C       null
 Math       A       A
 Music      null    A
```

Comment: Show your expected output

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, Please check edited post with expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite you dynamic sql query as

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
  CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN `Name` = ''',
         `Name`, 
         ''' THEN grade END) ',
         `Name`)  
         )
  INTO @sql
  FROM table1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `Subject`, ', @sql, ' FROM table1 GROUP BY `Subject`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36b9a/3)

In your stored procedure you have to hard code your name column for you dynamic sql if you pass it as parameter then you can use case to check for column, for example

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ', nm ,' = ''', nm, ..
```

Above part of procedure will evaluated as `MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'name' ..` because variable `nm` contains 'name' it will not recognize it as column

```
DROP PROCEDURE `sptest1`; 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `sib`.`sptest1`(IN nm VARCHAR(50),IN sub VARCHAR(50))
    BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
   CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN ',nm,' = ''',CASE WHEN nm = 'name' THEN `Name` END,''' THEN grade END) ',CASE WHEN nm = 'name' THEN `Name` END)
  )
  INTO @sql
  FROM table1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', sub ,',', @sql, '  FROM table1 GROUP BY ', sub ,'');
/*select @sql; */
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70c66/1)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I want to pass `Name` and `Subject` as a parameter to store procedure.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, Did understand? Why I am passing `Name` as a parameter? Because it may be change as per the requirement dynamically.

Comment: @Meem you have to define you columns name in `case` statement for multiple columns change case to `CASE WHEN nm = 'name' THEN Name WHEN nm = 'other_col' THEN other_col WHEN nm = 'other_col2' THEN other_col2 END` and so on the logic is you have to hard code conditions for all your column names you pass it as a parameter

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, Okay fine! Thank you so much for your valuable time.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I need time to accept your answer.